# ScrollingView editable in height Xamarin.ios

Tags: layout, view, xamarin.ios, uiscrollview

I have been trying to create a ScrollingView on Xamarin.ios for several days now which shrinks and enlarges when I establish it, showing a larger scrollable part and hiding the empty part if necessary. I'm trying to handle it like this:

```
 ScrollView.ContentSize = new CGSize(View.Bounds.Width, ViewBackground.Bounds.Height - (StackEsercizio.Bounds.Height * 1));
```

This statement works partially, only when placed in the ViewDidAppear and only for the first time. Do you have any advice or solution?

Finally, I solved it on my own. For the growth of the community, place the solution on github at this link: https://github.com/aleledda98/MyfitnessApp/blob/master/CreaSchedaNew.cs
the scrolling view moves dynamically based on the number of letters entered on a specific UITextField, thanks to all the same <3

Comment: You could post the relevant code of `ViewBackground` and `StackEsercizio` so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: ViewBackground and StackEsercizio are object.

Comment: if you would the respective file xamarin.ios, https://github.com/aleledda98/MyfitnessApp/blob/master/CreaSchedaNew.cs

Comment: Use auto-layout and constrain your scrollView's **content** to the scrollView's `.contentLayoutGuide`

Comment: now, i know the problem, when i hide the stackview, scrollingview not change. when i comment StackES1.Hidden = true; scrolling view change. Why?